# read a file and get the top 3 words using a dictionary in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, counter

I made a function to make a dictionary out of the words in a file and the value is the frequency of the word, named read_dictionary. I'm trying to now make another function that prints the top three words of the file by count so it looks like this:
"The top three words in fileName are:
word : number
word : number
word : number"

This is what my code is:

```
 def top_three_by_count(fileName):

  freq_words = sorted(read_dictionary(f), key = read_dictionary(f).get,
   reverse = True)

  top_3 = freq_words[:3]
  print top_3
 print top_three_by_count(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
def top_three_by_count(fileName):
      return [i[0] for i in  Counter(read_dictionary(fileName)).most_common(3)]
```

Actually you don't need the `read_dictionary()` function at all. The following code snippet do the whole thing for you.

```
with open('demo.txt','r') as f:
    print Counter([i.strip() for i in f.read().split(' ')]).most_common(3)
```

Comment: It keeps returning a blank list

Comment: @djderik, what is the output of `print read_dictionary(f)`? Are you getting a valid dictionary?

Comment: Yes it prints out a dictionary. And the fileName is just a place holder for when I'm defining the function so that way after the function is created I just plug in the actual file name which in this case is f. It worked for the function for read_dictionary

Comment: I have just tested it again and it works perfectly. Don't know what is the problem in your end. We may check the output of   `Counter(read_dictionary(fileName))` to be sure. It should print a Counter object.

Comment: huh I don't know. Thanks though

Comment: @djderik, by the way, you don't need the `read_dictionary(fileName)` at all. See the updated answer.